# Nesting if in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I'm fairly new to bash scripts, so this is probably a stupid syntax error, but why is this code not working?

```
for x in $(ls)
do
  if [ -d $x ]
  then
  echo $x
  fi
done
```

The separate for and if section work fine on their own, but this produces no output.

Comment: As @geirha noted, you should not use `$(ls)` to drive your loop. `for x in *` is what you want here.

Comment: "ls" is fine where appropriate ;) "*" is equivalent (and slightly more "efficient", because it spawns one less subshell) to `ls -1`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Two things. Never use `ls` to iterate files, and quote parameter expansions `"$x"`. The for and if syntax itself is correct. I prefer to put the `do` and `then` on the same line though

```
for file in *; do
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        echo "$file is a directory"
    elif [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        echo "$file is a regular file"
    fi
done
```

For learning bash, I recommend reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide most other tutorials and guides are unfortunately not very good.

The reason for not doing `for x in $(ls)` to iterate files is because `for` iterates *words* and `ls` outputs lines with filenames. if those filenames happen to contain whitespace, those filenames will be split up further into words, so you'll be iterating the *words* of the filenames, not the filenames. Obviously, for the simple cases that works, but why use a half-working solution when there's a shorter and more elegant way that handles all cases?

With `for x in *` the shell replaces the `*` with all filenames matching that pattern in the current directory (called pathname expansion), and each filename will be a separate word so it will work no matter what characters the filename contains. Filenames can contain any character (including newlines), except `/` and the NUL byte (\0).

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more on that.

As for using `[[` vs `[`. `[` is a command inherited from the bourne shell, used to test strings, files and numbers. Bash has added a more powerful `[[` keyword that can do everything `[` can and more. If you're writing an sh script, you must use `[`, but in bash scripts you should use the more powerful `[[` and `((` syntaxes. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for more about the difference between `[` and `[[`.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on that? Why shouldn't you use ls?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between double square brackets and single?

Comment: This is a great answer, really well explained.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe there's a problem with the characters being used to separate the different parts of the statement?

What if you tried:

```
for x in $(ls); do if [ -d $x ]; then echo $x; fi; done
```

Does that produce output?

Answer (score 1):

1) the syntax is perfectly legal

2) Yes, you can nest "if/else" blocks inside a loop.  You can also nest inner loops within an outer loop :)

3) "if [ -d $x ]" checks if "x" is a "directory".

If you don't see any output, then perhaps you don't have any subdirectories?

SUGGESTION:

- open a terminal window
- Run your script.  See whether or not you get any output.
- If not, then type `mkdir moose`.  This will create a subdirectory called (uncoincidentally) "moose".
- Re-run your script.  You should see *at least* "moose".

Comment: 3) Yeah I know, I was trying to produce an output of directories. I definitely have directories, it was run from ~, still no output, so something's amiss.

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/bin/bash

name=c
for command in "cd $home" " cd XSStrike" "python xsstrike.py"
do
    if [[ $name == "c" ]]; 
    then
        echo "<==========> access granted <==========>"
        $command
    else
        echo "<==========> access denied <==========>"
    fi
done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.